# Memory friendly dummy values?

Tags: php, memory

I have to store some distinct numeric values in an array and then when comparing against new values, I have to check if they already exist or not.

I found that the fastest way to do this was to set the values as array keys and check using `isset()` if it exists or not, i.e. :

```
foreach($myvalues as $value) {
    $myarray[$value] = 'some dummy value';
}

//initialize some new values

$result = isset($myarray[$newValue])? 'value already exists' : 'new value!';

echo $result;
```

I was wondering, what would be the most efficient value to put in place of `'some dummy value'` ? Currently I'm using `true` keyword

Comment: Sure, `true` is fine. `null` would be fine too, but would force you to use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset`.

Comment: How about [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?.

Comment: too slow. I have to check 300*45000 values every run

Comment: $myarray = array_flip($myvalues);

Comment: Depending on your use case a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomfilter) (like [this one](https://github.com/deceze/BloomFilter)) before an `in_array` *may* be the best solution.